# XML to JSON Convertor Using JSON Schema in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, jsonschema

I'm trying to convert an xml to json data using the java-json.jar . The conversion is done. but have issues with the resulting JSON data like

- An Integer is expected but the data is converted as String.
- it would not create a list if there was only one child element ( even when it should be a list as per the JSON schema ).

Is there any way to convert XML into JSON based on the JSON schema in Java?